# JSValue init(bool:in:) vs JSValueMakeBoolean()

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, javascriptcore

I am playing around with the JavaScriptCore framework and have discovered two different ways to create booleans in a JavaScript context:

```
import JavaScriptCore

let context = JSContext()

let trueVal = JSValue(bool: true, in: context)
JSValueIsBoolean(context?.jsGlobalContextRef, trueVal?.jsValueRef) // true

let otherTrueValue = JSValueMakeBoolean(context?.jsGlobalContextRef, true)
JSValueIsBoolean(context?.jsGlobalContextRef, otherTrueValue) // true
```

What is the difference between `JSValue(bool:in:)` and `JSValueMakeBoolean`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generated header for `JSValueRef` keeps this comment:

```
 * Copyright (C) 2006 Apple Inc.  All rights reserved.
```

And for `JSValue`:

```
 * Copyright (C) 2013 Apple Inc. All rights reserved.
```

Seems JavaScriptCore framework was first developed for an old OS X (showing 10.5+ in [the reference page](https://developer.apple.com/reference/javascriptcore)) with C-function based APIs. And later it has come to iOS with a modern class based APIs.

(Though, I have never used JavaScriptCore in such old OS X.)

I haven't explored JavaScriptCore so deeply inside it, so I'm not sure such C-function based APIs still needed in some cases or not.

But usually, you have no need to touch C-function APIs. For example, you can use `isBoolean` property rather than C-function `JSValueIsBoolean`.

```
if let trueVal = JSValue(bool: true, in: context) {
    print(trueVal.isBoolean) //->true
}
```